# Pycharm cannot find refernce to .so file

Tags: python, pycharm, .so

Pycharm shows an error when trying to import a .so file, in my case the filename of the source file is 'connector_base.cpython-38-darwin.so' and I am trying to import it in the following way:

```
import connector_base
```

All the other imports in the project (for files which are not .so) work fine.

Also the file runs as expected since I have a setup.py that takes care of this, but I would like for this error and similar to disappear on Pycharm.

Comment: How is the extension module shared object being placed on the Python path? Are you using CPython 3.8 on darwin architecture?

Comment: 1) Ah I am not sharing it at all, how can I do that? Does this process need to be repeated for every .so file?

Comment: 2) Yes Darwin (MacOS) and yes python 3.8